# Formatting a plotly plot with many subplots in R

Tags: r, plotly

please I have the following data and plot with subplots:

```
library(plotly)

# Create example data
set.seed(123)
df <- data.frame(
  DATE = seq(as.Date("2021-01-01"), as.Date("2021-01-10"), by = "day"),
  FEATURE1 = rnorm(10),
  FEATURE2 = rnorm(10),
  FEATURE3 = rnorm(10),
  FEATURE4 = rnorm(10),
  FEATURE5 = rnorm(10),
  FEATURE6 = rnorm(10),
  FEATURE7 = rnorm(10),
  FEATURE8 = rnorm(10),
  FEATURE9 = rnorm(10),
  FEATURE10 = rnorm(10)
)

# Reshape data from wide to long format
df_long <- tidyr::pivot_longer(df, cols = -DATE, names_to = "Feature", values_to = "Value")

plots <- lapply(unique(df_long$Feature)[-1], function(feature) {
    plot_ly(df_long[df_long$Feature == feature, ], x = ~BUSINESS_DATE, y = ~Value, type = "scatter", mode = "lines",
            line = list(color = "blue"), showlegend = FALSE, text = paste0("Feature: ", feature)) %>%
      layout(yaxis = list(  title = list(text = feature),
                            title_font = list(size=20),
                            tick_font = list(size = 20)
                          ),
             annotations = list(
               list(x = 0.5, y = 1, text = feature, showarrow = FALSE, xref = "paper", yref = "paper",
                    font = list(size = 6))
             )
             )
  })
  subplot(plots, nrows = 5)
```

The issue I face is that I the tick size on the y-axis doesn't take into account the value I'm passing (20 in this example). I can't find any example that shows how to fix my code. Any thoughts? Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that `yaxis` has no attribute `tick_font` (or `title_font`). To set the tick size use `tickfont = list(size = 20)`. For the axis `title` use  e.g. `title = list(font = list(size = 20))`

```r
library(plotly, warn = FALSE)
#> Loading required package: ggplot2

plots <- lapply(unique(df_long$Feature)[-1], function(feature) {
  plot_ly(df_long[df_long$Feature == feature, ],
    x = ~BUSINESS_DATE, y = ~Value, type = "scatter", mode = "lines",
    line = list(color = "blue"), showlegend = FALSE,
    text = paste0("Feature: ", feature)
  ) %>%
    layout(
      yaxis = list(
        title = list(
          text = feature,
          font = list(size = 20)
        ),
        tickfont = list(size = 20)
      ),
      annotations = list(
        list(
          x = 0.5, y = 1,
          text = feature,
          showarrow = FALSE,
          xref = "paper",
          yref = "paper",
          font = list(size = 6)
        )
      )
    )
})
subplot(plots, nrows = 5)
```

[image]

Comment: that's fantastic, thank you! I would have expected R to through an error message if I were passing wrong parameters, but I guess that's not the case. Thank you

Comment: Nop. When you have a look at the docs, i.e. `?plotly::layout`, you will see that only two arguments are explicitly specified, which are `p` aka a plotly object and `data`. Everything else is passed on via `...` as there are too many attributes to state them all explicitly. As a result when you use a wrong attribute name it will most of the time simply have no effect. But in the docs there is a link to the plotly API where all possible attributes or options are listed and documented.